# realtime collaborative editing: mobwrite on windows7 x64

Tags: python

I have set up [Mobwrite](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobwrite/) on my Win7 development machine using the daemon and q.py listener.  The client test suite passes, but when I run the server test suite, everything fails with this sort of response:

```
Question:
U:user10259538167863824
f:0:unittest10259538167863824
R:0:Hello world

Expected:
u:user10259538167863824
F:0:unittest10259538167863824
D:0:=11

Actual:
u:user10259538167863824
F:0:unittest10259538167863824
D:0:=11

Diff:   
u:user10259538167863824
¶
F:0:unittest10259538167863824
¶
D:0:=11¶

¶

¶
```

I am assuming it has something to do with line endings, but I don't know what to do.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks so much!

PS: I'm running Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

The MobWrite support group would probably be the best place to ask this:
http://groups.google.com/group/mobwrite

I agree that the unit tests are probably failing due to line endings.  MobWrite always uses \n for its line endings.  If the unit tests (an XML file) were transferred using ASCII to a Windows box, then it sounds quite reasonable that they would have been injected with \r\n line endings.

I'll see if I can recreate this tomorrow.  In the mean time, if all the unit tests 'fail' like this, then I'd accept that MobWrite is running fine and that the tests are just bogus.  Carry on with development!

Comment: I am unable to recreate this error.  Which browser are you using?  In server.html, line 228, could you change 'diffString' to 'escape(diffString)' and rerun the test?  That will generate more verbose output that should identify exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It happens in Chrome 8.0.552.224/FF 3.6.12/IE 8.0.7600.16385

Also, I'm running q.py with CGI, not mod_python.

Here are the results RAW:

```
%3CSPAN%20TITLE%3D%22i%3D0%22%3Eu%3Auser680700127966702%3C/SPAN%3E%3CINS%20STYLE%3D%22background%3A%23E6FFE6%3B%22%20TITLE%3D%22i%3D21%22%3E%0D%3C/INS%3E%3CSPAN%20TITLE%3D%22i%3D22%22%3E%26para%3B%3CBR%3EF%3A0%3Aunittest680700127966702%3C/SPAN%3E%3CINS%20STYLE%3D%22background%3A%23E6FFE6%3B%22%20TITLE%3D%22i%3D50%22%3E%0D%3C/INS%3E%3CSPAN%20TITLE%3D%22i%3D51%22%3E%26para%3B%3CBR%3ED%3A0%3A%3D11%3C/SPAN%3E%3CDEL%20STYLE%3D%22background%3A%23FFE6E6%3B%22%20TITLE%3D%22i%3D59%22%3E%26para%3B%3CBR%3E%3C/DEL%3E%3CINS%20STYLE%3D%22background%3A%23E6FFE6%3B%22%20TITLE%3D%22i%3D59%22%3E%0D%26para%3B%3CBR%3E%0D%3C/INS%3E%3CSPAN%20TITLE%3D%22i%3D62%22%3E%26para%3B%3CBR%3E%3C/SPAN%3E
```

...and decoded for easier reading:

```
<SPAN TITLE="i=0">u:user680700127966702</SPAN><INS STYLE="background:#E6FFE6;" TITLE="i=21">
</INS><SPAN TITLE="i=22">&para;<BR>F:0:unittest680700127966702</SPAN><INS STYLE="background:#E6FFE6;" TITLE="i=50">
</INS><SPAN TITLE="i=51">&para;<BR>D:0:=11</SPAN><DEL STYLE="background:#FFE6E6;" TITLE="i=59">&para;<BR></DEL><INS STYLE="background:#E6FFE6;" TITLE="i=59">
&para;<BR>
</INS><SPAN TITLE="i=62">&para;<BR></SPAN>
```

...and here is the server output for the test suite

```
INFO:mobwrite:Read 0 settings from ./lib/mobwrite_config.txt
INFO:mobwrite:Listening on port 3017...
INFO:mobwrite:Running cleanup task.
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
WARNING:mobwrite:Truncated data: '
'
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
WARNING:mobwrite:Rollback from shadow 1 to backup shadow 0
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
WARNING:mobwrite:Rollback from shadow 1 to backup shadow 0
INFO:mobwrite:Got 1b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '-1  +Hello world' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '+Hello world' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '-1' delta: ''
WARNING:mobwrite:Delta failure, expected 0 length: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent empty raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '-5   +Goodbye        =6' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=13' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '-5   +Goodbye        =5' delta: ''
WARNING:mobwrite:Delta failure, expected 11 length: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Idle out: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '=11' delta: ''
WARNING:mobwrite:Delta failure, expected 0 length: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent empty raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Idle out: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '=11' delta: ''
WARNING:mobwrite:Delta failure, expected 0 length: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent empty raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 51b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '-1' delta: ''
WARNING:mobwrite:Delta failure, expected 51 length: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent 51b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 0b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '+A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) ; / ? : @ & = + $ , #' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '-1  +A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) ; / ? : @ & = + $ , #' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '-1' delta: ''
WARNING:mobwrite:Delta failure, expected 7 length: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent 13b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 0b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '+a%00b%25c%0Ad' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got 1b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '-1  +a%00b%25c%0Ad' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 3b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '-1' delta: ''
WARNING:mobwrite:Delta failure, expected 3 length: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 0b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '+a%E3%81%86b' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got 1b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '-1  +a%E3%81%86b' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 3b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=1  -1      +%0A    =1' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 2b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '=1   +%0D%0A =1' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=1  -1      =2' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '-5   +Goodbye        =6' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=13' delta: ''
WARNING:mobwrite:Rollback from shadow 1 to backup shadow 0
INFO:mobwrite:Got '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '-5  +Goodbye        =6' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '-5   +Goodbye        =6' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=13' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '=9   -2      +m' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '-5  +Goodbye        =5' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '-5   +Goodbye        =6' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=13' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '-5   +My     =6' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '-2  +Goodbye        =6' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 2b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=2' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 2b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '+a   =2' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=3' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '=2   +d' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '+a  =3' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 2b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=2' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 2b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Got '+1   =2' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=3' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '=2   +4' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=3' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Expired buffer: 'testbuffer1_3'
INFO:mobwrite:Executing buffer: testbuffer1_3
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Expired buffer: 'testbuffer3_3'
INFO:mobwrite:Executing buffer: testbuffer3_3
INFO:mobwrite:Expired buffer: 'testbuffer4_3'
INFO:mobwrite:Executing buffer: testbuffer4_3
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
ERROR:mobwrite:Invalid buffer: 'testbuffer5 0 0'
ERROR:mobwrite:Invalid buffer: 'testbuffer6 0 1'
ERROR:mobwrite:Invalid buffer: 'testbuffer7 1 2'
INFO:mobwrite:Executing buffer: testbuffer8_1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '-5   +Goodbye        =6' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=13' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
WARNING:mobwrite:Rollback from shadow 2 to backup shadow 1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '-5   +Goodbye        =6' delta: ''
WARNING:mobwrite:Repeated delta: 0 '
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 11b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got 13b raw text: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '=13' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '=11' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '-5  +Goodbye        =6' delta: ''
INFO:mobwrite:Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1
WARNING:mobwrite:Rollback from shadow 2 to backup shadow 1
INFO:mobwrite:Got '=11' delta: ''
WARNING:mobwrite:Repeated delta: 0 '
INFO:mobwrite:Sent '-5  +Goodbye        =6' delta: ''
```

Comment: Also, it isn't just the unit tests failing... mobwrite isn't working when i hook it up to a textarea either